# How do hide Groups from a user role unless they're permitted via ACL

Tags: groups, permissions, acl

I see that ACLs allow one to permit a user role to view selected Groups, however, something is enabled somewhere allowing all users to view all the Groups.  I don't have the permission setup allowing the user role to Edit Groups... so why are they able to view all the Groups?

Ideally, the non-admins would only be able to view Groups that are added via the ACL.

Comment: disable view all contact permission then it will block group view

Comment: If I disable this... how do I allow a user role to view all the contacts?

Comment: Create two or three role - initially have all the user in a group "without view all contact" - Once you want a specific user to view all contact change the user to a different role - This should work

Comment: This ends up giving them access to all the Groups.  What I'd like is for a user to have the ability to search and view all the Contacts but not be able to view the entire list of Groups.

Comment: We have the same question...
@flantascience did you finally find out how to do what you wanted ?